# Confirmation Required regarding script

Tags: bash

I am making a small script which zipps a file and then copy it to another dir. But when i execute it; the file gets zipped but on copying it gives following error:

```
cp: missing destination file operand after /home/centoslive/Desktop/new
```

following is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(gzip jawad.txt)

cp $file /home/centoslive/Desktop/new
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the line:

```
file=$(gzip jawad.txt)
```

Captures the output of `gzip` onto `stdout` into the variable `file`. If `gzip` succeeds, it will write a file `jawad.txt.gz`, but it generates no output on `stdout`, so the `file` variable will be empty.

Then your `cp` line (after expansion of the empty `$file`) looks like:

```
cp /home/centoslive/Desktop/new
```

Which is missing the destination that `cp` thinks you want to copy `/home/centoslive/Desktop/new` to.

Instead, you probably just want to do:

```
cp jawad.txt.gz /home/centoslive/Desktop/new
```

You might consider something like:

```
src=jawad.txt
dst=/home/centoslive/Desktop/new

if gzip $src; then
    cp $src.gz $dst
fi
```

This way, you only do the copy if the `gzip` succeeds. You could put an `else` in there to handle the case when it fails.